# Na+ as an electrophile

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, alkali-metals

In inorganic I learnt that s block cations are lewis acids but while learning attacking reagents in organic chemistry I came across the fact that Alkali metals are not electrophiles, why so?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of lithium (and its diagonal partner magnesium from the alkaline earth metals), the cation is very much an electrophile. When either an organolithium compound or a Grignard reagent reacts with a substrate having a polar functional group such as a carbonyl group, not only does the carbanion-like hydrocarbon portion attach to the electrophilic end of the substrate. The lithium or magnesium ion equally acts as an electrophile, attaching to the negative end of the dipole (like the oxygen in the carbonyl group). This electrophilic-attack component actually promotes the nucleophilic attack at the other end of the dipole where the carbon-carbon bond that makes the headlines is formed.

Comment: is the reason why li+ can still pose as an electrophile and na+ can't (both being positive and having a stable configuration) because of the charge density/size?

Comment: The question was about alkali mrtals, so. LI was fair game. Yes charge density is a major factor. Lithium ion is also known to act electrpohilically in other settings such as displacing carbon dioxide and water when we attempt to precipitate the bicarbonate (so we ger lithium carbonate instead).